# jQuery condense show hide script for multiple elements

Tags: jquery, html, forms, simplify

Oh Man, I totally screwed up my last question...must have been sleepy or something :-)  Let's try this again.

I am a 20 year HTML vet who never did much javascript-ing etc. but have found a need over the years.  My coding is very elementary and mainly cut and paste then change it to make it work :-)

I'm creating a site where you can select the number of textfields with radio buttons.  The textfields selected are shown and required dynamically and the rest are explicitly hidden and unrequired so a user can select say 3 names and then 2 names and the third name and higher will not block submission due to the requirement being released.

What I have now works, but is fugly to say the least.  I'm calling changes on click for show, hide, required = true and required = false for all elements AND for each radio button.  too much code!

I'd love some suggestions for turning this into 1 code snippet that handles everything...anyway on to the code!

## CSS

```
body,td,th {
font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: medium;
}
body form select {
font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: medium;
}
.submit {
font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: medium;
}
body form {
text-align: center;
margin-top: 10px;
}
.submission {
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
height:500px;
width:400px;
border:#000000 solid 3px;
float:left;
padding: 20px 0;
}
.center {
margin:0 auto;
width: 812px;
}
.left{
text-align:left;
}
.right{
float:; 
}
.eighty{
width:80%;
}
.marg_20{
margin-left:20px;
}
.marg_40{
margin-left:40px;
}
.marg_60{
margin-left:60px;
}
.content{
display:none;
}
.up20{
margin-top:-20px;
}
.signMain{
width:200px;
height:100px;
background:WhiteSmoke ;
margin:20px auto 0;
}
.test{
width: 198px;
height: 20px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 5px;
font-size:20px;
text-align:center;
}
.submitDiv {
height: 100px;
}
.signCreatorDiv {
height: 400px;
}
.namesColumn{
width:200px;
height:350px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

## jQuery

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('.NameRad1').click(function() {
$('div.NameImg.content:lt(1)').show();
$('div.NameImg.content:gt(0)').hide();
$('input#textBox.test:lt(1)').attr("required",true);
$('input#textBox.test:gt(0)').attr("required",false);
});
$('.NameRad2').click(function() {
$('div.NameImg.content:lt(2)').show();
$('div.NameImg.content:gt(1)').hide();
$('input#textBox.test:lt(2)').attr("required",true);
$('input#textBox.test:gt(1)').attr("required",false);
});
$('.NameRad3').click(function() {
$('div.NameImg.content:lt(3)').show();
$('div.NameImg.content:gt(2)').hide();
$('input#textBox.test:lt(3)').attr("required",true);
$('input#textBox.test:gt(2)').attr("required",false);
});
$('.NameRad4').click(function() {
$('div.NameImg.content:lt(4)').show();
$('div.NameImg.content:gt(3)').hide();
$('input#textBox.test:lt(4)').attr("required",true);
$('input#textBox.test:gt(3)').attr("required",false);
});
});//]]>  
</script>
```

## HTML

```
    <body>
<form action="https://im-here.foxycart.com/cart" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<div class="center">
<!--Begin leftSide-->
<div class="submission">    
<!--Begin hiddenInputs-->
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="I'm Here Notification Sign" />
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="10" />
<!--End hiddenInputs-->
<!--Begin colorSelection-->
<div class="left eighty center">
<label>Color</label>
<br>
<select id="colorSelect" name="Color" tabindex="1" required >
<option value="" selected="selected" disabled>Choose A Color...</option>
<option value="Black">Black</option>
<option value="DarkGrey">Brushed Aluminum</option>
<option value="DarkKhaki">Brass</option>
</select>
</div>
<!--End colorSelection-->
<br>
<!--Begin nameSelection-->
<div class="left eighty center">
Number Of Names
<br>
<input type="radio" name="Names" value="1{p+100}" id="Names_1" class="NameRad1 trigger textBox1" tabindex="5" required />
One <br>
<input type="radio" name="Names" value="2{p+200}" id="Names_2" class="NameRad2 trigger textBox2" tabindex="6"  />
Two <br>
<input type="radio" name="Names" value="3{p+300}" id="Names_3" class="NameRad3 trigger textBox3" tabindex="7" />
Three <br>
<input type="radio" name="Names" value="4{p+400}" id="Names_4" class="NameRad4 trigger textBox4" tabindex="8" />
Four <br>
</div>
<!--End nameSelection-->
<br>
<!--Begin columnSelection-->
<div class="left eighty center">
Number Of Columns
<br>
<input type="radio" name="Columns" value="1" id="Columns_0" class="ColumnRad1 " tabindex="3" required />
One
<br>
<input type="radio" name="Columns" value="2" id="Columns_1" class="ColumnRad2 " tabindex="4"  />
Two
<br>
</div>
<!--End columnSelection-->
<br>
<!--Begin fontSelection-->
<div class="left eighty center">
<label>Font</label>
<br>
<select id="fontSelect" name="Font" tabindex="2" required>
<option value="" selected="selected" disabled>Choose A Font...</option>
<option value="Arial">Modern</option>
<option value="Times New Roman">Classic</option>
<option value="Impact">Vintage</option>
<option value="Verdana">Retro</option>
</select>
</div>
<!--End fontSelection-->
</div>
<!--End leftSide-->
<!--Begin rightSide-->
<div class="submission">
<div class="signCreatorDiv">
<div class="signMain"></div>
<div class="namesColumn">
<div class="NameImg content" >
<div class="NameTxt1 right test"  >
<input class="test" type="text" name="name #1" id="textBox1" value="" placeholder="Name 1" tabindex="9" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="NameImg content" >
<div class="NameTxt2 right test " >
<input class="test" type="text" name="name #2" id="textBox2" value="" placeholder="Name 2" tabindex="10"  />
</div>
</div>
<div class="NameImg content" >
<div class="NameTxt3 right test"  >
<input class="test" type="text" name="name #3" id="textBox3" value="" placeholder="Name 3" tabindex="11"  />
</div>
</div>
<div class="NameImg content" >
<div class="NameTxt4 right test"  >
<input class="test" type="text" name="name #4" id="textBox4" value="" placeholder="Name 4" tabindex="12"  />
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="submitDiv">
<input type="submit" name="x:productsubmit" id="productsubmit" value="Add My Sign" class="submit" tabindex="13"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<!--End rightSide-->
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

As you can see, the jQuery is fairly redundant and I know what I want it to say just not the syntax etc.  I want: if selected indexN of radio buttons then show and require <=textBox indexN and hide and un-require >textBox indexN

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks for reading!

## UPDATE

so from user [j08691](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616443/j08691) I got this code which is perfect for the problem above IN MY SPECIFIC page:

```
$('input[name="Names"]').click(function () {
var idx = $(this).index(':radio')
$('.namesColumn input:text').hide().prop("required", false);
$('.namesColumn .NameImg.content').show();
$('.namesColumn .NameImg.content:lt(' + (idx + 1) + ') input:text').show().prop("required", true);
})
```

it works perfectly. :-)

Comment: A user responded to my last question with this code:


    `$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fontSelect").on('change', function(e) {
    var index = $(this)[0].selectedIndex;       
    $(".NameImg:lt(" + (index) + ")")
    .show()
    .find("input[type='text']")
    .attr('required', true);
    $(".NameImg:gt(" + (index-1) + ")")
    .hide()
    .find("input[type='text']")
    .attr('required', false);
    });    
    });`

which should work
and this jsfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sWpKn/)

Comment: Side note, name attributes shouldn't have spaces.

Comment: yep thanks for that...although I haven't' been using those names...they were left in for some shopping cart functionality

Comment: Oh and IDs **must** be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('input[name="Names"]').click(function () {
    var idx = $(this).index(':radio')
    $('.namesColumn input:text').hide().prop("required", false);
    $('.namesColumn .NameImg.content').show();
    $('.namesColumn .NameImg.content:lt(' + (idx + 1) + ') input:text').show().prop("required", true);
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EzxAj/1/)**

And remember that IDs must be unique and name attributes shouldn't contain spaces.

Comment: This answer seems to be going where I want...thanks so much!  I will test it in the actual page and then probably accept it as the correct answer :-)

Comment: hmmmmm.  I added this to my page and since I actually have more than one set of radio groups I think calling them by class or id may be in order...

Comment: If I change the names of the radio button elements to be "Names" instead of "Number of Names" and the also edit the code to be:

`'input[name=Names]:radio'...`

it works...any reason not to do that?  how would i make it class based?

`'input[class=trigger]:radio'` doesn't work...

Comment: well, no luck...adding: `'input[name=Names]:radio'`... doesn't work on the main page...the reason i did: `div.NameImg.content:lt(3)` initially was because I was having a hard time calling the text boxes specifically, now it seems like I'm having a hard time calling the radio buttons...

Comment: Well by the jsFiddle example you can see that it works, so it's just a matter of getting your element selectors setup properly. You may want to update your question with proper name attributes and IDs. That may allow me to tailor my answer further.

Comment: I updated the HTML snippet with the correct names and the full html for that page.  Thanks for all your help...

Comment: Let me know if this seems to do what you need http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EzxAj/1/

Comment: YEAH!  your are the man...or woman :-)  Now can we talk a little bit about WHY it works?  I'd really like this to be some learning on my part...Thanks again

Comment: The only difference was the change in selectors. Oh, BTW, you had name attributes with spaces in them again (`name="name #3"`) and in my example I changed them to `name="name3"`. That and I had to unhide the containing div as well (`$('.namesColumn .NameImg.content').show();`). That wasn't in your original example.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific example, one helper function would suffice. Something like:

```
function showHide(idx1, idx2){
    $('div.NameImg.content:lt('+ idx1 +')').show();
    $('div.NameImg.content:gt('+ idx2 +')').hide();
    $('input#textBox.test:lt('+ idx1 +')').attr("required",true);
    $('input#textBox.test:gt('+ idx2 +')').attr("required",false);
}
```

Called like this:

```
$('.NameRad1').click(function(){showHide(1,0)});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ysPvd/

HOWEVER, if you know the structure of your markup won't change, then it's possible to actually use the element itself to determine what arguments to pass when calling your function. Something like this:

```
$(':radio').click(function(e){
    var idx = $(this).index()
    showHide(idx, idx+1);
});
```